# How do i move multiple objects at the same time but every object by different distance in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have a game that generates multiple objects and which object comes to other side of canvas wins. When you press button every object moves a different random distance forward. The problem is that firts object moves the least and last object moves the most. So last object always wins. How do i made it that random object will win and not always the last one.

```
import tkinter
import random
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

label=tkinter.Label(text='set amout of cars')
label.pack()

entry=tkinter.Entry()
entry.pack()

def car():
    global move
    move=0
    canvas.delete('all')
    p=int(entry.get())
    for i in range(p):
        canvas.create_rectangle(20,20+i*20,40,30+i*20, fill='coral')

move=0

def race():
    global move
    canvas.delete('all')
    p=int(entry.get())
    for i in range(p):
        rand=random.randint(5,20)
        move=move+rand
        canvas.create_rectangle(20+move,20+i*20,40+move,30+i*20, fill='coral')
    
    
        
button=tkinter.Button(text='start', command=car)
button.pack()
button2=tkinter.Button(text='forward', command=race)
button2.pack()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: don't use for-loop for this. Create function which makes small step for every object and later repeate it using `root.after(millisecond, update_positions)`

Comment: all your object use the same variable `move` and in every loop you add new values to this value - so first object use distance `move+rand1`, second `move+rand1+rand2`, third `move+rand1+rand2+rand3`. Every object should have own variable with position - or better create objects only once and get object_id and later use `canvas.moveto(object_id)` to move it without creating new object.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the comments, every object shares the same `move` variable, so each object starts where the last one stopped.

The better solution is to call the `move` method on the canvas for each of the objects. You can either save a list of objects or just ask the canvas to give you the objects. You can then use `randint` to decide how much to move each item.

The `race` function would look something like this:

```
def race():
    for car in canvas.find("all"):
        delta_x = random.randint(5,20)
        delta_y = 0
        canvas.move(car, delta_x, delta_y)
```

Answer (score 1):

All your objects use the same variable `move` - so in every execution of `race` they use the same position. But in every loop you add new values to `move` - so first object use distance `move+rand1`, second `move+rand1+rand2`, third `move+rand1+rand2+rand3`, etc - and this makes problem.

Every object should have own variable with position.

So it would need to use list with positions.

---

Or better create object only once and get `ID`

```
car_id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
```

and later use `ID` to move this object

```
canvas.move(car_id, ...)
```

and this way every car will use own position.

And of course it also need to use list to keep all `IDs`

---

```
def restart():
    canvas.delete('all')
    all_cars.clear()

    number = int(entry.get())

    for i in range(number):
        car_id = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20+i*20, 40, 30+i*20, fill='coral')
        all_cars.append( car_id )

def race():
    for car_id in all_cars:
        distance_x = random.randint(5,20)
        distance_y = 0
        canvas.move(car_id, distance_x, distance_y)

# --- main ---

all_cars = []
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code:

I also used

- `after(100, race)` - so it automatically repeate function after 100ms and you don't have to click button `race` again and again.
- `canvas.corrds()` to get current position and check if it end of race.
- `create_line` to show finish line

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def restart():
    canvas.delete('all')
    all_cars.clear()

    number = int(entry.get())

    for i in range(number):
        car_id = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20+i*20, 40, 30+i*20, fill='coral')
        all_cars.append( car_id )

    # finish line
    canvas.create_line(360, 10, 360, 30+(number-1)*20 + 10, fill='red')
    
def race():
    winner = False
    
    for car_id in all_cars:
        distance_x = random.randint(5, 20)
        distance_y = 0
        canvas.move(car_id, distance_x, distance_y)

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(car_id)
        
        if x1 >= 360:
            winner = True
            canvas.moveto(car_id, 360, y1-1)
            canvas.itemconfig(car_id, fill='green')

    if not winner:
        root.after(100, race)
    
# --- main ---

all_cars = []  # list for all IDs

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text='set amout of cars')
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='start', command=restart)
button.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='forward', command=race)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]